# reduce size of a div plus all its contents to fit in a smaller div jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this has been asked but its not meeting my main problem. I have a div that has text and images most of them absolutely positioned. They are dynamically added by user, so we can't know how they are formatted. I want to reduce the div plus all its content to fit on smaller screen and keep all ratios.

[image]

Php or jquery is welcome. I have tried

```
     var div=$('.largercontainer').html();
     $('.smallercontainer').html(div);
```

But the text and images don't reduce size even if they fit. Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: `width: 1080px;` won't work ~ try `width: 100%`

Comment: have you tried percent values for all other absolutely positioned elements?

Comment: Is it possible to replicate on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: if its all about image resolution stability your concerned about then nailthumb jQuery plugin is what would you need. http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php

Comment: I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gscq1jqw/ , @eddie B, I cant use percentage because its a business card design web app and the card size must meet the standard size. In the fiddle, you will notice there is a lot of inline styling. This is because its done dynamically by the client using drag and drop, resize handles e.t.c.

Comment: @mike, I cant alter the content of the div or styles, Please check my project here www.thecardguys.co.ke

Comment: @dreamweiver, actually your solution will help me out on another issue, but on this one, like in the fiddle, the elements are being misplaced

Comment: If you used fixed values ~ they're fixed... so don't use them... find another solution such as media queries to determine viewport size... You need to learn about [Responsive Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: @Eddie B, seems it will work on my case. Let me try out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is define a size in width and height and change apply it to your container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".largercontainer").css({
        width: '200px',
        height: '150px'
    });
});
```

this will reduce the div width and height

i hope this might help you

Comment: Hey @meenesh jain, I had thought of your solution. Its actually changing the container, but the elements are not being changed proportionately check http://jsfiddle.net/gscq1jqw/

Comment: let me check the link